# phpmyadmin which users can I delete?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a fresh install of phpmyadmin on my vpn server.  It has some users on it that my cpanel did not.  Which of these can I safely delete please?

```
User    Host    Password    Global privileges 1     Grant   Action  
debian-sys-maintlocalhostYes    ALL PRIVILEGES  Yes     Edit Privileges
phpmyadmin  localhost   Yes     USAGE           No      Edit Privileges
root        127.0.0.1   Yes     ALL PRIVILEGES  Yes     Edit Privileges
root        localhost   Yes     ALL PRIVILEGES  Yes     Edit Privileges
root        tomtgg      Yes     ALL PRIVILEGES  Yes     Edit Privileges
```

Comment: If these are not visible on your cPanel it's for a good reason.

Comment: It's probably more a question of "What would you like to break?" :-)

Comment: Still, good question. +1

Comment: @BoltClock I think he means he switched from a shared package to a VPS and now has these users. @David is `tomtgg` your working machine?

Comment: Hi Pekka, yes, tomtgg is the only user I made, everything else was just their at the start from install...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suspect this will soon be bumped to serverfault.com real-soon-now™, but...

- **debian-sys-maint** - Don't delete it, it's important: https://serverfault.com/questions/9948/what-is-the-debian-sys-maint-mysql-user-and-more
- **phpmyadmin** - Used for phpMyAdmin. If you delete it, you'll break phpMyAdmin
- **root** (x3) - These are just different hostname access rights for the root user. (I presume "tomtgg" is your hostname.) In essence, all of the entries are there to ensure that the root user has local access under a variety of conditions.

In short, you shouldn't delete any of these.

Comment: It *could* be argued that it would be better to have a limited user access the box from `tomtgg` instead of root. Other than that, +1

Comment: @Pekka Know what you mean and pretty much agree (I'd usually lock things right down and ssh in), but I suppose it depends on the set up.